# Add HTML tags around each unix GREP result

Tags: html, bash, ubuntu, grep

I'm working on a script to get certain text from a log file and post it to an html file. The problem I'm having is that I'd like each result of the grep to be inside `<p></p>` tags.

Here's what I have so far:

```
cat my.log | egrep 'someText|otherText' | sed 's/timestamp//'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using `egrep` and `sed`

You currently have:

```
$ echo 'timestamp otherText' | egrep 'someText|otherText' | sed 's/timestamp//'
 otherText
```

To put para-tags around the text, add just one substitution to the `sed` command:

```
$ echo 'timestamp otherText' | egrep 'someText|otherText' | sed 's/timestamp//; s|.*|<p>&</p>|'
<p> otherText</p>
```

#### Using `awk`

```
$ echo 'timestamp otherText' | awk '/someText|otherText/{sub(/timestamp/, ""); print "<p>" $0 "</p>"}'
<p> otherText</p>
```

Or, getting input from the file `my.log`:

```
awk '/someText|otherText/{sub(/timestamp/, ""); print "<p>" $0 "</p>"}' my.log
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `sed` to wrap the lines:

```
cat my.log | egrep 'someText|otherText' | sed -e 's/timestamp//' -e 's/^/<p>/' -e 's#$#</p>#'
```

You can use `-e` to execute multiple operations on each line. `^` matches the beginning of the line, `$` matches the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version with a single sed:

```
sed -n 's#\(timestamp\)\(.*\)\(someText\|otherText\)\(.*\)#\<p\>\2\3\4\<\\p\>#p' my.log
```